# Binding in directive linking not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a simple directive work which will simply return uppercase text. The text is passed from a controller through a binding.

The basic idea is:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">

    <div uppercase>{{main.message}}</div>

</div>
```

And my main JS file is as follows:

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function(){
    this.message = 'hello world'
})

.directive('uppercase', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
        link: function(scope, el, attr) {
            el.text() = el.text().toUpperCase();
        }
    }
})
```

Also my jasmine test is as follows:

```
describe("App", function() {

    var $compile
    ,   $rootScope
    ,   $controller
    ,   MainCtrl
    ,   element;

  beforeEach(module('app'))

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$controller_){

    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $controller = _$controller_;

    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl');



  }))

  describe("MainCtrl", function() {
    it("should have a message property", function() {
      expect(MainCtrl.message).toBe('hello world');
    });
  });

  describe("Uppercase directive", function() {
    it("should return uppercase text", function() {      

      element = '<p superman>{{MainCtrl.message}}</p>';

      element = $compile(element)($rootScope);

      $rootScope.$digest();

      expect(element.text()).toBe('HELLO WORLD');
    });
  });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$timeout` to wait for Angular bindings to complete and this is how you would use `.text()`:

```
.directive('uppercase', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
        link: function(scope, el, attr) {
            $timeout(function(){
                el.text(el.text().toUpperCase());
            });
        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sENgx/)**</kbd>

Comment: awesome... how did you know this would work? what is the thought process behind it...

Comment: @Ishan I got `{{MAIN.MESSAGE}}` as the result initially. So I decided to use `$timeout` which gives some time to `{{}}`s to evaluate.

Comment: how can i unit test it? i cannot run $timeout in my specs right?

Comment: I am quite unsure if this is a good solution. Depending on server performance, a simple $timeout could possibly not be "enough"

Comment: @Sprottenwels What in your opinion should be used to replace $timeout?